# How to add add_meta_box to specific Page Template?

Tags: custom-field, pages, metabox

I want to add **add_meta_box** to specific **page**  type like Page Template, Like Product Template.

I am using this article http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/ to try it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your custom page template filename is `foobar.php`, you can use `get_post_meta()`:

```
global $post;
if ( 'foobar.php' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) {
    // The current page has the foobar template assigned
    // do something
}
```

Personally, I like calling this inside my `add_meta_boxes_page` callback, and wrapping it around the `add_meta_box()` call itself.

```
function wpse82477_add_meta_boxes_page() {
    global $post;
    if ( 'foobar.php' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) {
        add_meta_box( $args );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', 'wpse82477_add_meta_boxes_page' );
```

You'll just need to instruct users to *save the page* after assigning the template, so that the meta box appears.

Comment: Thanks a lot, one prob here to inform user to save page once. BTW its saved ma lot time. Thanks CHIP

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Couldn't remember if `add_meta_boxes` was too early for this. Might suggest using `if( 'foobar.php' == get_page_template_slug( $post->ID ))` over using the meta-key directly.

Answer (score 4):

I found a few bugs with the answer above option above but I customized this option below and it helped - no bugs at all.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_product_meta');
function add_product_meta()
{
    global $post;

    if(!empty($post))
    {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'page-templates/product-page.php' )
        {
            add_meta_box(
                'product_meta', // $id
                'Product Information', // $title
                'display_product_information', // $callback
                'page', // $page
                'normal', // $context
                'high'); // $priority
        }
    }
}

function display_product_information()
{
    // Add the HTML for the post meta
}
```

https://paulund.co.uk/display-post-meta-box-specific-page-templates

It's clean

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with name of the page :

Accueil is the name of the page.

```
    $screens = ['Accueil'];
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
     if ( get_the_title() == $screen ) {//condition
     add_meta_box(
      'accueil_données',
      'Informations sur Orchestre',
      'metabox_accueil_infos',
      'page',
      'normal',
      'high'
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function mcf_add_custom_metabox() {
    global $post;
    if ( $_REQUEST['post'] == 30 ) {
        add_meta_box( 'shop_editor', ' ', 'mcf_callback', 'page' );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', 'mcf_add_custom_metabox' );
```

I got a way to add metabox in specific page using page id.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Hard coding is never a good idea. ;)