# Add metabox to pages that use custom template in WordPress

Tags: metabox, page-template

I am trying to add custom metaboxes to only those pages that use a certain custom template that is applied to them.

How can i do this? I based on this this guide:
[How to add add_meta_box to specific Page Template?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82477/how-to-add-add-meta-box-to-specific-page-template)

But it doesn't work for me. How come?

This is my code in functions.php:

```
add_action("admin_init", "metabox_bookmaker");
function metabox_bookmaker(){
    global $post;
    if ( 'page-templates/template-bookmaker.php' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) {
        add_meta_box("metabox_bookmaker_custom", "Metabox per Single Bookmaker", "custom_metabox_bookmaker", "page", "normal", "high");
    }
}
```

Comment: Meta boxes should be added using the [`add_meta_boxes` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes/) or post-type-specific hooks like `add_meta_boxes_page`. And with these hooks, you'd get the correct post object for the current post without having to access the `$post` global.

Comment: Great, thank you so much, I was almost there, but your response anticipated and confirmed what I was thinking. Now it works!